# Alternating background colors for list tile flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

[image: Sample Image]

From the sample image, you see that there are different background colours for `listTile` children inflated on the `listView`. The way it works is first item gets white, second grey, third white, fourth grey and so on. That means even and odd item count gets varying but consistent colors.

I already know how to set the `backgroundColor` but what kind of algorithm can I use to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a listview builder, you can use the index from the itemBuilder to alternate between the backgroundcolor.

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: listItems.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return Container(color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.pink : Colors.orange);
    }
  )
```